# Qt5 QOpenGL does not draw anything

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I'm using a Widget inheriting `QGLWidget` to show an OpenGL viewport inside my Qt application.
The Widget does nothing more than creating three `CRenderVector`s and drawing them all the time.

A `CRenderVector` is simply a group of a `QVector3D`, a `QOpenGLVertexArrayObject` and three `QOpenGLBuffer`s for vertices, indices and colors.

The vertex buffer objects get created with

```
const GLFloat color[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
color_buffer.create();
color_buffer.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
color_buffer.bind();
color_buffer.allocate(color, sizeof(color);
color_buffer.release();
```

respectively, using `0, 0, 0` and `vec().{x,y,z}()` for the `vertex_buffer`.

The vertex array object gets created via

```
vertex_array.create();
vertex_array.bind();
    vertex_buffer.bind();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, (void*)0);

    index_buffer.bind();

    color_buffer.bind();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, (void*)0);
vertex_array.release();
```

Drawing of a vector looks like

```
vertex_array.bind();
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, elements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
vertex_array.release();
```

The problem is, that I can't see anything in the viewport except the clearing color although I think I'm using everything like shown in the [official Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/classes.html#o). Where did I misunderstand Qt or OpenGL documentations?

The stripped project for QtCreator can be downloaded at [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/download/hrrf4s3cha4z4p1/stackoverflow_demo.tar.gz).

Comment: is index buffer a defined as a element array in the constructor?

Comment: `vertex_buffer` and `color_buffer` are `QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer`s and `index_buffer` is a `QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer`

Comment: @Uroc327 the most minimal amount of change to see something is to move the call to `view_projection.perspective` up a line (set perspective before modelview). And to change it to `view_projection.perspective(45, ratio, 0.01, 10);` (negative near values are nonsense for perspective projection, they only work in orthographic projection)

Comment: @PeterT Add it as an answer.